# Writing controllers using geometry information

Tags: drake

Suppose I have rigid bodies and I want to do some typical manipulation tasks where I want to do computations based off the geometry, specifically the surface normals.

Is it possible to do this directly over the Drake meshes / Drake convex shapes (e.g. not having to route through a slow pointcloud representation first)?

How to access the surface normals?

Answer (score 1):

`SceneGraph` has two primary entry points for geometry computations: [`QueryObject`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html) and [`SceneGraphInspector`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_scene_graph_inspector.html). If you want to figure out how to compute geometry-related quantities, you should always look there.

In this case, you probably want the [`ComputeSignedDistanceToPoint`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html#aa4c7754ca66a8593b182ae990643875c) method.

Comment: I'm not sure this works for getting the closest surface normal vector to a point. For example, if I have a polyhedron, and the closest point on the polyhedron to my target point is an edge - the gradient of the signed distance will not produce a surface normal

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct access to the geometric information. One can extract various forms of information via the current APIs. They *might* be enough for you to achieve your end. But they are likely not.

Can you elaborate on what kind of operation you would want to do that is dependent on surface normals?

Comment: For example, writing a grasp sampler based on antipodal points. Or, for any object, getting a surface normal on the bottom of object so we know the final placement pose of that object is stable.

Comment: Are these possible right now in Drake? @Sean Curtis

Comment: Grasp sampling with antipodal points is implemented as an example [in my course notes](https://manipulation.csail.mit.edu/clutter.html#section4).

Comment: @RussTedrake Yes but this example is divorced from multibodyplant. I suppose a workable solution right now is to use a third party library like trimesh to access the normals of the object in the body frame, then get the transformations from multibodyplant to transform the trimesh normals to do the computations. But this is not ideal, adds a lot of boilerplate

Comment: So, it seems like what you're kind of looking for is a query where you'd give a direction and want to know what the extremal point in that direction might be (the anti-podal). It's a bit trickier when the point isn't unique or the shape isn't convex.

Aside from that hypothesis, can you more concretely characterize the information you *have* and what information you'd like to get? (i.e., the parameters and return type of a hypothetical function.)

Comment: Sure, so one example is a function get_normals_at_current_pose(mbp, instance_index) -> num_surface_normals, 3. This would return an array of surface normals for the rigid body in the current body orientation. Another function that would be needed is get_surface_centroids_at_current_pose(mbp, instance_index) -> num_surfaces, 3, which returns the surface geometric centers of the instance.

Comment: These two quantities would be enough, I think, to easily create an antipodal grasp planner

Comment: So, you're simply looking for raw data. You've got a piece of geometry rigidly affixed to a body and you just want a bunch of normals and points (face centroids), one per normal, measured and expressed in some frame as defined by the body's pose. So, you've clearly got meshes in mind and not primitive shapes (boxes, spheres, etc.) And I assume your term "surface" means triangle/polygon on the mesh.

Is that basically it?